# frequency as "index" in Pandas dataframe and dynamic extension

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am working on an RF-project and the workflow is as follows:

1. Define `start`, `stop`, `step` of the desired frequency sweep
2. Calculate the specific line impedance `Z0` and frequency dependent effective permittivity `eef` for every frequency
3. Calculate the Transmission matrix `ABCD` for every f
4. From ABCD calculate the scattering Parameters S (complex valued)
5. Calculate the magnitude of the params
6. Finally plot them

At the moment I have it implemented with lists/numpy-arrays being filled in a for-loop. This works but is ugly and labor intensive when I want to daisychain multiple ABCD's.
The issues are a difficult debugging (loosing temporary results between the aforementioned steps.

I think a solution might be using pandas but I have difficulties to implement the following necessities:

1. Create dataframe with the frequency as the index (a column for f might work too)
2. expand the columns "on the fly" to store the results for every f
3. individually set `dtype=` for some colums because currently `dtype=np.clongdouble` is necessary (otherwise I get div by zero in latter calculations)
4. one column containing a numpy-array (the abcd-matrix)

I've searched around but the results didn't clarify the needed concepts and my approach like

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> start = int(100E6)
>>> stop = int(1E9)
>>> step = int(1E6)
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(start,stop+step,step),columns=["z0","eef"])
>>> df.index
RangeIndex(start=100000000, stop=1001000000, step=1000000)
>>>
```

throws errors when I try to access `df.index(1000)` or `df[1000]`

Comment: You have defined a dataframe with the lowest index being 100E6, you get an indexing error for df[1000] since that doesn't exist in you datafame.  Also, better to access the df by row using df.iloc[r] where r is the row number

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had written a reply which I was not able to edit (too old) so I deleted it. The solution to access rows by frequency like `f=100000000` is to use `loc` instead of `iloc`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(start,stop+step,step),columns=["foo","break","baz"])
df.loc[100000000]
```
gives the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After messing around for a while I am fine with the following

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Z0', 'eef', 'A', 'B', 'C',
                      'D', 's11', 's12', 's21', 's22'], index=f, dtype=bool)
    df.index.name = 'Frequency'
```

with `f = [*range(start, stop+step, step)]`. Then I am accessing the necessary column/row by `df["A"].loc(f)`. Even if the column is not used in further calculations I stick to this scheme because I had too much hassle to distinguish between Dataframes with(-out) specific columns. During the process the `dtype=` is expanded to `complex` but that's working like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it more future proof, one can create a function that helps one calculate the S-params given `f_start`, `f_stop`, `f_step`, and the functions `Z0`, and `eef`. Here I will consider one has already the functions `Z0` and `eef`.

Let's call the function `calc_s` (the comments make it self-explanatory)

```
import pandas as pd

def calc_s(f_start, f_stop, f_step, Z0, eef):

    # Create a dataframe with the frequency column
    df = pd.DataFrame({'f': pd.Series(range(f_start, f_stop, f_step))})

    # Calculate Z0 and eef and add them to the dataframe
    df['Z0'] = df['f'].apply(Z0)
    df['eef'] = df['f'].apply(eef)

    # Calculate the ABCD matrix for every frequency
    df['A'] = 1
    df['B'] = 2 * df['Z0'] * df['eef']**0.5
    df['C'] = 1
    df['D'] = -2 * df['Z0'] * df['eef']**0.5

    # Calculate the scattering parameters S
    df['S11'] = (df['A'] + df['B']) / (df['A'] - df['B'])
    df['S12'] = 2 * df['C'] / (df['A'] - df['B'])
    df['S21'] = 2 * df['C'] / (df['A'] - df['B'])
    df['S22'] = (df['A'] - df['B']) / (df['A'] + df['B'])

    # Calculate the magnitude of the scattering parameters
    df['S11_mag'] = df['S11'].apply(lambda x: x.real**2 + x.imag**2)**0.5
    df['S12_mag'] = df['S12'].apply(lambda x: x.real**2 + x.imag**2)**0.5
    df['S21_mag'] = df['S21'].apply(lambda x: x.real**2 + x.imag**2)**0.5
    df['S22_mag'] = df['S22'].apply(lambda x: x.real**2 + x.imag**2)**0.5

    return df
```

Note that if needed, one cal always adjust the calculations, or change it to other that one might want/need, be it removing, adding,...

Now, let's test the function above with some dummy data

```
f_start = 1
f_stop = 100
f_step = 1
Z0 = lambda f: 50 # This is a dummy function that returns 50 for every f
eef = lambda f: 1 # This is a dummy function that returns 1 for every f
df = calc_s(f_start, f_stop, f_step, Z0, eef)

[Out]:
   f  Z0  eef  A      B  ...       S22   S11_mag   S12_mag   S21_mag   S22_mag
0  1  50    1  1  100.0  ... -0.980198  1.020202  0.020202  0.020202  0.980198
1  2  50    1  1  100.0  ... -0.980198  1.020202  0.020202  0.020202  0.980198
2  3  50    1  1  100.0  ... -0.980198  1.020202  0.020202  0.020202  0.980198
3  4  50    1  1  100.0  ... -0.980198  1.020202  0.020202  0.020202  0.980198
4  5  50    1  1  100.0  ... -0.980198  1.020202  0.020202  0.020202  0.980198

[5 rows x 15 columns]
```